# Inserting data according to table linked by foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling, opc-ua

I am collecting data that is generated by a machine. At the moment I use the software OPC Router to transfer the machine data via OPCUA into a MySQL database managed by phpMyAdmin. To increase performance and reduce the storage used, I thought of modeling the DB somehow like that:

[image]

Now I am asking myself:
If the machine is sending the data (e.g. machine name "5264"), can the database automatically enter the according FK "machine_ID" from "machines" table into the "machine1" as an integer instead of entering the machine name "5264"?

I already tried to write the data in an extra table first then insert a trigger after insert there. This trigger should then execute an insert command for each column into the according tables with the matching IDs instead of the full names. Here I failed because I was not able to execute more than one insert command in one trigger even though I used BEGIN and END.

The code I used for the trigger looks like that:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO products(Name)
        SELECT t1.Product_Name
        FROM transfer_data t1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT products.Name
                    FROM products t2
                   WHERE t2.Name = t1.Product_Name)

    INSERT INTO operators
        (operators.First_Name, operators.Last_Name)
        SELECT t1.Operator_First_Name, t1.Operator_Last_Name
        FROM transfer_data t1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT operators.First_Name, operators.Last_Name
                     FROM operators t2
                     WHERE t2.First_Name = t1.Operator_First_Name
                     AND t2.Last_Name = t1.Operator_Last_Name)
END;
```

Looking forward to hear your opinion about my plan and hopefully receive some help.

Comment: A trigger can have as many inserts as you want as long as they aren't to the table which fired the trigger. You can set NEW. values in a before insert trigger. You may wish to publish your trigger code.

Comment: @P.Salmon I added the code I used for the trigger. Maybe you can explain me what I have to change that it works. Or maybe you have an even better solution to insert the data the way I like without a helping table (here called "transfer_data")

Comment: Every Statement needs to be terminated and if you have more than 1 statement in your stored program than you need to set delimiters please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: I would expect to see reference to OLD. or NEW. values in a trigger plea review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much @P.Salmon! I made it work now with the following code:

```
Delimiter //

Create trigger this_one after insert on transfer_data
For each row

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO products(Name)
            SELECT t1.Product_Name
            FROM transfer_data t1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT products.Name
                        FROM products t2
                    WHERE t2.Name = t1.Product_Name);

        INSERT INTO operators
            (operators.First_Name, operators.Last_Name)
            SELECT t1.Operator_First_Name, t1.Operator_Last_Name
            FROM transfer_data t1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT operators.First_Name, operators.Last_Name
                    FROM operators t2
                    WHERE t2.First_Name = t1.Operator_First_Name
                    AND t2.Last_Name = t1.Operator_Last_Name);
    END
    //

delimiter ;
```